# Update XAML control property value from control's code but keep binding

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

I have written a control with a bindable property. This control also has a *method* to modify that property's value:

```
public class MyControl : ContentView // WPF: inherited from UserControl
{
  // Xamarin:
  public static readonly BindableProperty MyValueProperty = ...
  // WPF:
  // public static readonly DependencyProperty MyValueProperty = ...

  public int MyValue
  {
     get { return (int) GetValue(MyValueProperty); }
     set { SetValue(MyValueProperty, value); }
  }

  public void Reset()
  {
    MyValue = 0;
  }
}
```

I am using that control in a normal XAML page and update `MyValue` via binding:

```
<local:MyControl x:Name="TheControl"
                 MyValue="{Binding MyValueSource, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

The binding initially propagates changes from `MyValueSource` to `MyValue`. But as soon as I call the `Reset()` method once, the binding is overwritten by the `0` and updates to `MyValueSource` are no longer pulled.

I suppose any direct assignment of `MyValue` is intended to replace a `OneWay` binding. With a `TwoWay` binding, the change is just propagated back to `MyValueSource` and the binding remains functional.

If `Reset()` was in the view model, I could do this:

```
public void Reset()
{
  // TheControl.MyValue = 0; // Bad practice, destroys the binding
  MyValueSource = 0; // Good practice, preserves the binding
}
```

I don't want to implement the reset logic (which is more complex than in this reduced example) in every VM though, so it's located in the view/control.

So I wonder - *can* you assign a bindable property's value from **the control's** code behind and still preserve a possible `OneWay` binding? I know this means the VM does not get the changed value; binding `OneWay` is likely not correct if the control updates the property as well; you should rather use a `TwoWay` binding then.

But if someone says `OneWay` in XAML, I'd rather have it behave that way down to the wire than implement some "`OneWay` until you call `Reset()`" behavior.

Side note: I am working in Xamarin, but I guess the behavior is the same for WPF.

Comment: Could you paste the code for MyValueSource ? does it implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: "but I guess the behavior is the same for WPF". While there is no BindableObject/BindableProperty in WPF, its DependencyObject has a SetCurrentValue method, which does not remove the Binding.

Comment: @robert Yes it does. Also, the binding works fine for several changes of MyValueSource - up until to the point where I call the `Reset()` function for the first time. Then, in spite of calling OnPropertyChanged in the setter, the getter of MyValueSource is never called again.

Comment: @Clemens BindableObject, BindablePropery and BindingContext vs. DependencyObject, DependencyProperty and DataContext - it's different names for the same purpose. `SetCurrentValue` is actually the answer to my question for WPF. For Xamarin, BindableObject does not seem to have anything alike. If you can verify this and post that as answer, I can accept it.

Comment: What if you cast your BindingContext to your view model type and then set `MyValueSource` on the ViewModel from the Reset method in the code behind for the control?

Comment: @jgoldberger The control cannot know the view model type at design time. Otherwise, you could not use that control in any other context, in which case building a separate control makes no sense in first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taken and fleshed out [from @Clemens' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505179/update-xaml-control-property-value-from-controls-code-but-keep-binding#comment70216895_41505179):

### WPF

You can use the [`SetCurrentValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx) method on an [`DependencyObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx) (i. e. the control) to change the current effective value of a [`DependencyProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx). Unlike [`SetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setvalue.aspx), with `SetCurrentValue` any triggers, data bindings and styles to that property remain intact.

```
public void Reset()
{
  // this.SetValue(MyValueProperty, 0); // Replaces the binding
  this.SetCurrentValue(MyValueProperty, 0); // Keeps the binding
}
```

Remember that if you defined a `OneWay` binding, the view model will **not** be notified about the changed value, and that any change to the VM's `MyValueSource` property will override the control's value again (if the property is implemented correctly).

---

### Xamarin

There is currently no proper way to assign a [`BindableProperty`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty/)'s value without replacing a `OneWay` binding attached to it. [`BindableObject`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject/) (the control's base class) does not have any method comparable to WPF's `SetCurrentValue` and [`SetValue`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue/p/Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty/System.Object/) will allways replace the binding.

However, if you change the binding to `BindingMode.TwoWay`, the internal value change is propagated back to the view model. You should probably do this anyway to keep the control and the VM synchronized.

```
public void Reset()
{
  // Replaces any OneWay bindings
  // Updates MyValueSource for TwoWay bindings
  this.SetValue(MyValueProperty, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you and Clemens! I had a similar issue with Visibility property in WPF, when I wanted to implement a closable info bar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Hacky WPF equivalent for Xamarin, for OneWay binding:

```
public static class BindingObjectExtensions
{
public static Binding GetBinding(this BindableObject self, BindableProperty property)
        {
            if (self == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(self));
            }
            if (property == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(property));
            }
            var methodInfo = typeof(BindableObject).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("GetContext");
            var context = methodInfo?.Invoke(self, new object[] { property });

            var propertyInfo = context?.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredField("Binding");
            return propertyInfo?.GetValue(context) as Binding;
        }

public static void SetCurrentValue(this BindableObject self, BindableProperty property, object value)
        {
            if (self == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(self));
            }
            if (property == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(property));
            }
            var backupBinding = self.GetBinding(property);//backup binding
            var backupConverter = backupBinding.Converter;//backup orig. converter
            self.SetValue(property,value);//removes the binding.
            backupBinding.Converter = new DefaultValueConverter {DefaultValue = value};//change the converter
            self.SetBinding(property, backupBinding);//target should be updated to the default value
            var converterField = backupBinding.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredField("_converter");
            converterField.SetValue(backupBinding, backupConverter);//restore the converter
        }
}

//the default value converter class

[ContentProperty(nameof(DefaultValue))]
    public class DefaultValueConverter : BindableObject, IValueConverter, IMarkupExtension<DefaultValueConverter>
    {
        public object DefaultValue
        {
            get => GetValue(DefaultValueProperty);
            set => SetValue(DefaultValueProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty DefaultValueProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DefaultValue), typeof(object), typeof(DefaultValueConverter));

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return DefaultValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return DefaultValue;
        }


        public DefaultValueConverter ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return this;
        }

        object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return ((IMarkupExtension<DefaultValueConverter>) this).ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        }
    }
```